# How does adiabatic cooling make a nebula colder than the CMB?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, temperature, work, adiabatic

According to measurements, the gas from the [Boomerang Nebula](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/image_feature_405.html) is expanding so fast that it's colder than the cosmic microwave background radiation... how does such a simple mechanic work on such a massive scale? Where is the gas donating the energy to? The fabric of spacetime?

Comment: Your question is a good one. You are asking upon what the expanding nebula is doing work on? There is are particles in space and these carry momentum. This can act as the external pressure. Otherwise, it would undergo free expansion.

Answer (score -1):

The gas used its heat energy to accelerate itself to high speed.

It takes a lot of energy to get to a fast expanding motion.

Probably the gas is accelerating very little at this moment, so it's warming up in cosmic background radiation, or whatever other radiation there may be.

Comment: To the down voter: Ideal  gas is the simplest thing in the universe. I am dumb as brick but I can see that ideal gas cools when it expands to vacuum.

Comment: But it's not really expanding into the vacuum, it's expanding in the presence of a photon bath at 3 K. The question was not about why the gas cools, but rather why it's able to cool to a temperature _below_ that of the surrounding photon bath.